# monaca dosen't load www/index.html

Tags: android, ios, cordova, reactjs, monaca

I'm using monaca(onsenui-react) to create cordova app.

After type `monaca preview` I have checked app on browser like this.
But the `index.html` wasn't one I expected.

I mean have edited the www/index.html, but it's not loaded on browser.(I don't know what index.html was loaded)
Of course I typed `monaca preview` after edit www/index.html.

Does anyone can help me?

Comment: Can you give send a snippet of code or a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `monaca transpile` to transpile (kind of a compilation) your code into the **www** folder.

Using `monaca preview` will use the "webpack.dev.config.js" configuration to generate a compilation to a temporary folder. Using the "transpile" command will use the "webpack.prod.config.js" to compile your code into the **www** folder.

One more thing: monaca uses a strage combination of folders and package versions (most of them deprecated) to transpile, so I recommend you to do this manually if you are not using the monaca tools (the online paid stuff).

Recently I made a repo with everything already set up (using Onsen UI and React, also Redux - which is easily removable), using the latest version for every npm package (Webpack 2 being the most important, instead of the version 1 used by monaca) and keeping everything in your project folder (in your package.json, like it should be). You can find it [here](https://github.com/cristovao-trevisan/react-onsenui-minimal).